# Calculate the kilometre state of the auto with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to calculate the km state of each auto and show the viewer the result.
So my xml-file looks like this:

```
<pc:auto name="auto1">
<pc:basics year="2015" km="84.496"/>
</pc:auto>
<pc:auto name="auto2">
</pc:auto>
<pc:autos>
```

I am trying to write a small script that can calculate the km-state of each auto and give a description of it, so I calculate first the age of the auto and then calculate normal km-score, which the auto should have:

````
<xsl:variable name="normal_auto_km_state" select="/auto_age * 12.000"/>```
But it doesn't work, maybe someone can show me, where is the mistake
````

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context. Also state which XSLT version your processor supports (you cannot calculate age without knowing the current year, which is not available in XSLT 1.0).

Comment: Did you mean `$auto_age` (instead of `/auto_age`)?

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.